# How can I see which WiFi networks require authentication on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, authentication

On Windows 7, my list of available WiFi networks has no indication of which ones are open and which ones require an authentication key.

Is there some way to change the settings so I get **a visual cue** of which ones are open vs. locked?

Comment: It's supposed to be shown as in WinXP...  http://g2.stahuj.centrum.cz/magazin/7638/wi-fi.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless networks that do not have security enabled will be identified with a **yellow shield icon**. See this page of MS for more info: [How do I know if a wireless network is secure?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/How-do-I-know-if-a-wireless-network-is-secure)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be shown as in Windows XP. Take a look at this screen shot.

[image]

You can see the second one is unsecured and the other is "connected". But if there is one secured, it will show "WPA2... etc"